# Add on to an existing value in a field

Tags: sql, postgresql

In MySQL I would do something along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO "playerhours" ("uid", "playtime", "port") 
VALUES ('user1', 1337, 7780) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "playtime" = "playtime" + 1337
```

I tried the following but after a bunch of searching I wasn't able to find how to do the same in postgresql

```
INSERT INTO "playerhours" ("uid", "playtime", "port") 
VALUES ('user1', 1337, 7780) 
ON CONFLICT("uid", "port", "date") 
  DO UPDATE SET "playtime" = "playtime" + 1337
```

so my question is how would I go about adding a number to the previous value of a field
(BIGINT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to catch the value from the variable `EXCLUDED`:

```
INSERT INTO "playerhours" ("uid", "playtime", "port") 
VALUES ('test1@steam', 1337, 7780) 
ON CONFLICT("uid", "port", "date") 
DO UPDATE SET "playtime" = EXCLUDED."playtime" + 1337;
```

Or if you only want to get the current value of a certain column:

```
INSERT INTO "playerhours" ("uid", "playtime", "port") 
VALUES ('test1@steam', 1337, 7780) 
ON CONFLICT("uid", "port", "date") 
DO UPDATE SET "playtime" = "playerhours"."playtime" + 1337;
```

Comment: I think it the intention was `SET "playtime" = "playerhours"."playtime" + excluded.playtime`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh, I see.. I couldn't read that in the question. But I guess it wouldn't be a stretch to extrapolate from my answer to this scenario :-) cheers